# DevExpress: Missing lables in XtraReport

Tags: c#, xml, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm writing an generator for XtraReports. The generator generates an XML file (Header, DetailBand, Footer).

After this i create a XtraReport object with this XML string and show it on the UI.

Now i have the problem that sometimes (after some controls, often more than 600) the report ends without displaying the remaining controls.

I do not know why the controls are missing. The XML file is fine.

Maybe someone had the same issue or knows why this happens.

Comment: Provide some code and report xml to identify the issue. It is hard to imagine things with words

Comment: I'm not sure what XML file and string you are talking about, can you describe this? Do you use XML serialization -SaveLayoutToXml / RestoreLayoutFromXml methods?  

In fact, you need either to create the whole report layout at runtime (e.g., populate the XtraReport.Bands and each Band.Controls collections) or bind a report to a data source object.  Note that the latter approach is always better in terms of performance.